# Установка одинакового ID для определённых элементов TD таблицы TABLE

Tags: html

Есть таблица:

> `<table><tbody><tr><td id="1"></td><td id="2"></td></tr><tr><td id="1"></td><td id="2"></td></tr></tbody></table>`

Как видите, у меня совпадают два ID у элементов TD. Можно ли в HTML установить одинаковый ID для всех элементов TD определённой колонки, как показано на картинке http://dnevnik2010.ucoz.ru/index/aa/0-35 ?

Comment: смысл ID - именно в его уникальности. то-есть выставить вы конечно можете - но обрабатываться будет только первый элемент.
можно поступить так:
<td class="some-class" id=UNIQ_ID_1 data-id="2015-02-12">...</td>
<td class="some-class" id=UNIQ_ID_2 data-id="2015-02-12">...</td>

и в JS-коде:

$('td.some-class[data-id="2015-02-12"]).some_actions();

Comment: Жаль. А вот такая функция возможна: document.getElementByAlt или ByTitle ?

Comment: @Никита___, вообще, вы можете использовать один и тот же ID в пределах одной страницы. Например, jQuery позволяет получить доступ к каждому из них:

    <tr id='first_row'>
        <td id='id'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='second_row'>
        <td id='id'></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    $('#first_row #id') - первый id
    $('#second_row #id') - второй id

Но как сказали - несколько теряется смысл ID.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за ответ. Решил не делать эти ID, потому что заменил на другое. И к тому же с этими ID запутаться можно, ведь у меня этих ячеек TD будет около 300...

Comment: а почему никто не хочет оставлять ответ на вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Как и говорилось в комментариях от @boris_U и @Lesperanza "id" нужен для **уникального** маркирования. Старайтесь использовать [class](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/klassy), но стоит учитывать еще и то, что у id **приоритет выше**.

Стоит также учитывать: *чтобы обратиться к элементу по его **классу** в [Javascript](http://site-on.net/create/html/5-selectori-css-tochechnoe-primenenie-svoistv-css-optimizaciya-html) **нет** такой встроенной **возможности**, вам придётся использовать вспомогательные функции + это не всегда кроссбраузерно.*